# Dart Read From Json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

New to the Dart Language and been trying to make an app, But i've been stuck on this problem for a while now and can't seem to solve it. I've been trying to read from the content from a Json file and use a random value generator to pick out which info form the Json to display,

ex

name: Roxxxer
Email: Roxxxer@hotmail.com

name: Roxxxer1
Email: Roxxxer1@hotmail.com

But every time I try to display any of these values I get this error:

[image]

This is the json class reader(?)

```
class Recept{
  final String title;
  final String body;

  Recept({this.title, this.body});

  factory Recept.fromJson(dynamic json){
    return Recept( title: json['title'] as String,
                    body: json['body'] as String,

    );
  }

  String toString() {
    return '{ ${this.title}, ${this.body} }';
  }


}



import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:randomfood/Recept.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      new MaterialApp(
          home: new AwesomeButton()
      )
  );
}

class AwesomeButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Button createState() => new Button();
}

class Button extends State<AwesomeButton> {

  String test;

  void onPressed() {
    setState(() {
      //This is where the random generator goes in and give a new place in the json file
    });
  }

  Future<String> LoadRecipesFromJson() async{
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test.json');
  }

  Future LoadRecipes() async{
    String jsonString = await LoadRecipesFromJson();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    Recept recept = new Recept.fromJson(jsonResponse);

    String ToString() {
      return '${recept.title}';
    }

    test = ToString();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    LoadRecipes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Random Recipe Generator!"), backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey),
        body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
                child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,


                    children: <Widget>[

                      new Text(test, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(50.0)),
                      new RaisedButton(
                          child: new Text("Random Recept!", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 20.0)),
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          onPressed: onPressed
                      )
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: It would be better if you copy the error here instead of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `StatefulWidget` you need to use the `setState()` method to update variables, even though you're calling the function in `initState`. The reason you have to is that you're using asynchronous data. `initState` isn't going to wait around for the data so you have to update the state yourself. After you update the state, it will call the `build` method again and rebuild the widget and your `Text` widget will be using the new value from the `test` variable.

Also, the `new` keyword is optional as of Dart 2.0.

**CORRECTION**: You can put a function inside of another function.

```
  Future<void> LoadRecipes() async{
    String jsonString = await LoadRecipesFromJson();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    Recept recept = new Recept.fromJson(jsonResponse);

    setState(() {
      test = recept.title;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You *can* put a function inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

The variable **test** may not have a value in the beginning as you are **asynchronously loading** value into test variable. 
While giving the test variable **inside Text(test) widget if test is null**, It'll give an error that you are getting right now. 
So to prevent this from happening just make a slight change in your code change

**This**

```
 new Text(test, style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
```

**to**

```
 new Text(test??"Loading", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
```

Now if the value of test is null you'll get **Loading** as the text otherwise whatever is the  value of the test.